# Does the iPhone SE have Sapphire glass?

Tags: iphone

Does the iPhone SE use stronger glass on its screen than iPhone 5S? Does it have Sapphire glass similar to iPhone 6 & 6S.

Comment: iPhone 6 and 6 S have glass displays. Sapphire crystal is only on some watches and most rear camera covers at this point. Could you clarify the last sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, just plain old Gorilla Glass.

[image]
Apple would have put it here, and it wasn't announced during the keynote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the iPhone SE has a Sapphire Crystal lens cover
http://www.apple.com/iphone-se/specs/

Comment: The question is about the glas, not about the lens cover.